# which coordinate system are x and y in?

Tags: coordinate-system

I am trying to figure out which coordinate system x and y are in?

For example,

1. for the address from Miami, Florida, the longitude is -80.2956825, latitude 25.94238253, and the corresponding x is 777815.1474 and y is 221416.4504.
2. for the address from Jacksonville, Florida, the longitude is -81.61880377, latitude 30.178197, and the corresponding x is 629037.1117 and y is 687872.4065.
3. for the address from Orlando, FLorida, the longitude is -81.50532129, latitude is 28.488564, and the corresponding x is 643746.0095 and y is 500510.776.

Comment: Guess: 1 and 3 are in state plane Florida East (not sure which GeoCRS/datum nor the units) while 2 is in Florida North.

Answer (score 2):

A quick search with [projfinder](http://projfinder.com/) revealed that those coordinates are in Florida GDL Albers. There are several possible datums, so depending on the datum used, it should be one of the following crs:

- [EPSG:3086](https://epsg.io/3086) NAD83 / Florida GDL Albers
- [EPSG:3087](https://epsg.io/3087) NAD83(HARN) / Florida GDL Albers
- [EPSG:3513](https://epsg.io/3513) NAD83(NSRS2007) / Florida GDL Albers
- [EPSG:6439](https://epsg.io/6439) NAD83(2011) / Florida GDL Albers

Comment: Thank you so much!